# On footer scroll keep it fixed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an issue i've been working on for a day or so, i'm making an online shop, where when you visit a specific item's page, you have a fixed [add to cart] button as a footer, and when i scroll to a specific point, it should become static, check this example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

the only difference is that i need it to be a header, not a footer.

here's my jquery code:

```
const myFunction = () => {
let lastScrollTop = 0

$(window).scroll(() => {
  const footerTop = $('.wrapper-footer')?.offset()?.top || null
  const container = $('.wrapper-mobile-price')
  const containerHeight = wrapperMobilePrice.height()
  const bottomOfScreen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()
  const st = $(window).scrollTop()

  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    if (bottomOfScreen > footerTop + (containerHeight / 2)) {
      container.css({position: 'static'})
    }
  } else {
    if (bottomOfScreen + containerHeight < footerTop) {
      container.css({position: 'fixed'})
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st
})
```

}

please help if you have any solutions, thanks!

Comment: add html and css pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using CSS sticky positioning? You can see an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

You should specify in which position an element should be fixed.
When an element reaches that position it becomes fixed.

```
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 500px;
}
```